# How to smoothly animate scaling of HTML5 canvas fillText()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

Running the script below in **IE9** produces a buttery **smooth** animation. But the same script when run in **Chrome20** (win & mac) produces a **wobbly** animation. How can i fix this?

Also I would appreciate if someone could provide a definite answer to the following related questions as well.

Does chrome support sub-pixel text rendering?

Does chrome support GPU based text rendering?

If so then please mention the exact version and OS the feature was added in.

http://jsbin.com/ijegam/2

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var i=12;
function f() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,500);
    ctx.font=i + "px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,350);
    i+=0.1;
}
setInterval("f()", 16);
</script>
```

In IE9 initially the animation is also a bit wobbly but after a few iterations it becomes extremely smooth.

Comment: This is an anti aliasing bug I think

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your answer is yes:  http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit

However, when I play with text resizing really slow, I notice that the text grows along the X, then the Y, then the X, then the Y, creating that choppiness, so maybe there is some other issue at play...

Try using requestAnimationFrame with the cross-browser shim instead of a timeout: 
http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

I created this to play with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iCABx

Hopefully that helps in some way.

> Does chrome support GPU based text rendering?

In this case, the text is a drawing on the canvas. Canvas2D hardware accelerated rendering was added in Chrome 18:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history
Other than the canvas, I can't say for sure, but I know CSS 3D hardware acceleration exists.

Comment: Any ideas whether solutions exist using Javascript based font rendering using webGL backend? I know at least Three.js does webGL based rendering in some demos.

Comment: You could try that.  Let me know what you get working.  A better solution might be to use CSS and simply transform scale the containing div.  Note that the text does go fuzzy while sizing this way, but once it's there, you maintain the same sharp anti-aliasing.  See example:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEGHB

Comment: Also, I got rid of the blurriness during the scale transform by starting with the font-size high and scaling down instead of up.  A solution for you might be to put the font-size as high as you'll ever want it, then scale it down initially on first page load.  Then, afterward, if the user scales it back up, it will scale up without going blurry.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jweIC

Comment: Just make sure the initial page load scale that you set doesn't have a transition effect.  Add the transition onclick, then remove it when it's done.

Answer (score 2):

If your text is just a single message a reasonable solution could be to just create a big text in a separate hidden canvas object and then drawing this as an image with the scaling you need.

Note also that scaling a text by changing the font size is quite different from just applying a transformation on it. In other words in general the shape of an 8pt font is not just the same of a 16pt font with everything scaled down 50%... the reason is for example that for readability and aesthetics you want the three legs of a small "m" character to by on exact pixel boundaries and equally sized and spaced... clearly this is not possible by simply shrinking the coordinates and the difference (especially on small fonts) can be huge.

If an animation of a text with smooth slow zoomming doesn't "wobble" then it simply means that the rendering (as text) is poor quality. But probably in that case what you want is a zooming on the image of a text... and that's what's the hidden canvas is.

Comment: Its a good idea, but sadly I have a lot of text messages. Also the zoom constraint are such that the user can zoom in very deep on the text. In order to prevent blurry text at high zoom levels I will have to render the image at a very high resolution, then copy and scale it before drawing it on the destination canvas. This can be very expensive.